# IOS 6.1 new Blob doesn't return Blob object

Tags: html, ios6, html5-canvas, blob

I have the following code to create a Blob out of the canvas toDataURL

dataURItoBlob = (dataURI) ->
    binary = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1])
    array = []
    i = 0

```
while i < binary.length
    array.push binary.charCodeAt(i)
    i++
uint = new Uint8Array(array)
new Blob [uint]
```

This works fine in chrome/ff/opera. But when I tried in my IPAD os 6.1 the new Blob returns [object Uint8Array]
Is there a issue in IOS 6.1

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To read Uint8Array you need to refer to [buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8Array).

```
new Blob([uint.buffer], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

That will fix it in iOS, but also default usage on chrome/ff/opera. My advice is to also add the correct contentType.